# Maximize sum of (n-combination) rows with constraint

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with 3 columns: Product, Cost, Revenue.

There are 1000 rows (1000 distinct Products).

My budget equals B.

I want to filter 3 Products so that I maximize the Revenue sum for those 3 products, provided that the total Cost for those 3 Products are less than my budget B.

Can this be done in Power BI?

I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you in advance.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't share any sets of data, I created a scenario with datasets. I hope It is similar to your case:

Please note that if you want to paste the code into your Power BI Desktop, please remember to remove "evaluate" statement. Also Table functions require you to create a new table to see the results unless you plan to use them as table expressions in your DAX code.

First create a table:

```
DEFINE
    TABLE FactTable = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS ({
    (102, 12.5, 14.5),
    (103, 20.5, 21.5),
    (104, 12.5, 13.0),
    (105, 23.5, 25.5),
    (106, 12.0, 15.0),
    (107, 10.0, 14.0),
    (108, 16.5, 18.5),
    (109, 25.0, 28.0),
    (110, 12.5, 18.0),
    (111, 14.5, 16.5),
    (112, 15.5, 17.5)
    },
    "Product",[Value1],
    "Cost", [Value2],
    "Revenue",[Value3])
    VAR MyBudget = 50.0
    EVALUATE
    FactTable
```

[image: SOP] [image: SOP01]

Now let's make some tests:

Most profitable products are the ones where [Revenue] - [Cost] are the greatest. Lets find out which products they are:

Code to test Top3 highest [Revenue] - [Cost] values:

```
TOPN (3,FactTable,[Revenue]- [Cost])
```

[image: CDG]

Note: Ties are included. That's why there are 4 rows.

Now let's find the most costly products:

```
TOPN (3,FactTable,[Cost])
```

[image: SOP04444]

Now It is time to build filter context of calculate. I mean we need to find the products where [Revenue] - [Cost] is greatest, and [Cost] is among the lowest sets of values. We will use EXCEPT() function in DAX.

```
EXCEPT(
        TOPN (3,FactTable,[Revenue]- [Cost]),
        TOPN (3,FactTable,[Cost]))
```

[image: ggg]

Let's test now if top 3 [Cost] values are less than my budget.(Here we are checking it against our variable "MyBudget= 50")

```
EVALUATE
        ROW("Top3 Total Less Than My Budget",SUMX(
        EXCEPT(
        TOPN (3,FactTable,[Revenue]- [Cost]),
        TOPN (3,FactTable,[Cost])),
        [Cost]
        )<= MyBudget)
```

[image: CVB]

And finally, since our test result is "True", we can write our final code to calculate the top3 revenue total using calculate function:

```
EVALUATE
        ROW("Top3 Total Revenue", CALCULATE(SUM(FactTable[Revenue]),
        EXCEPT(
        TOPN (3,FactTable,[Revenue]- [Cost]),
        TOPN (3,FactTable,[Cost]))
        ))
```

[image: SDA]

Comparison:

[image: DSADWQ]

I hope It can be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi Ozan Sen, thanks for the answer but I must clarify my question. I need to maximize ((Revenue(X) + Revenue (Y) +Revenue (Z)) such that (Cost(X) + Cost(Y) + Cost(Z)) < Budget.
For example, you answer is Products: 106, 107, 110, BUT better choice would be 106, 109, 110 because Total Revenue is higher (15+25+18) and the Total Cost fits in budget (12+25+12.5 is less than 50)

Comment: Hello @PQRST Are you sure ? I added above a comparison screenshot. Your 109 is 15 points higher in Cost even though 14 points higher in revenue. In this case, we should look at the [Revenue] - [Cost] values, and as you can see above, 107 performs better. (4.0 against 3.0)

Comment: Hi Ozan Sen, I do not want to maximize (Revenue - Cost), let say that Revenue are days, and Cost currency, in that case there is no logic to subtract those columns (even if you can subtract those columns I want to maximize sum of Revenue). I need to maximize sum of three rows from Revenue columns but with constraint that appropriate sum of Cost is less than budget. Your solution satisfy that Total Cost is less than 50, but Revenue of (18+14+15) is less than (15+18+28) so it is not maximized.